# How do i find the average of a floating point array in MASM?

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, masm, x87

I have an assignment due tomorrow and I need to find the average of the floating point values in an array. I can't seem to find anything relatively useful in the book or in my notes about converting an integer into a float (the value of 5 in ecx (array length) to 5.0 so I can divide without truncation).

This is the code I was given, there are only two lines marked line1 and line2 that need to be changed but I can't seem to figure out what they need to change to. Any ideas on how to make this work?

c++ file

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern"C"
{
    float average(float [], int);   // external assembly function prototypes
    float max(float [], int);
    float min(float [], int);
}


int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 5;
    float floatArr[SIZE] = {2.2, 3.75, 1.11, 5.9, 4.64};

    printf("The array contains the float numbers: ");

    for (int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++)
        printf("%f ", floatArr[i]);

    float val1 = average(floatArr, SIZE);
    printf("\n\nThe average of the floats are: %f\n", val1);

    float val2 = max(floatArr, SIZE);
    printf("The largest float is: %f\n", val2);

    float val3 = min(floatArr, SIZE);
    printf("The smallest float is: %f\n", val3);

    return 0;
}
```

asm file

```
.686
.model flat

.code 

_average PROC

        push ebp                ; save the caller frame pointer
        mov ebp, esp

        mov ebx, [ebp+8]    ; address of first element in array
        mov ecx, [ebp+12]   ; store size of array in ecx
        xor edx, edx        ; counter for loop
        fldz            ; set top of FPU stack to zero

loopAdd:
        fld dword ptr[ebx+edx*4]   ; load next array onto register stack at st(1)
        faddp              ; add st(0) to st(1) and pop register stack
        inc edx            ; increment counter
        cmp ecx, edx           ; compare size of array in ecx with counter in edx
        jg loopAdd         ; if ecx > edx jump to loopAdd and continue

line1   cvtsi2sd eax, xmm0      ;load array size as float to compute average
line2   fdivp                 ;divide st(0) by st(1) and pop register stack


        pop ebp            ; restore caller frame pointer
        ret                ; content of st(0) is returned 

_average ENDP

END
```

Comment: Why are you mixing x87 and sse instructions?

Comment: As someone new to MASM, I don't see anything harmful about this. Am I wrong? Could you take the time and explain?

Comment: Well it's not so much that it can't be done, but xmm0 is a completely different register than st(0) and you seem to be assuming they're related. To load an integer on the fpu stack, you can use something like `fild`.

Comment: I agree with @harold and use of [FILD](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_95.html). Don't use the SSE (SIMD instructions). If you're using the x87 FPU for most of the work, stick with it. The reason your _MASM_ assembler may not have been accepting SIMD instructions like `cvtsi2sd eax, xmm0`  is because it is an old version, or you need the `.XMM` directive as well as `.686`

Comment: Okay, so how would I use FILD?
"fild eax"?

Comment: I've tried and I've tried and I can't seem to figure it out. I've looked at a dozen websites and read two chapters in my book and I can't find anything about moving a register into memory, unless you mean to use the register's memory location instead.
I feel like I'm still missing something. 

    mov [eax], ecx
    FILD [eax]

I have an error: error A2023: in=▒

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Hold on a second, I got a number as an answer, but it's not the right answer and I'm not sure how to see what the values of the st(0) and st(1) are.

the lines of code I have are:
mov DWORD PTR[eax], ecx
FILD DWORD PTR[eax]

The answer I got was 5.000000

Comment: I've added an answer that may be one way to achieve what you are trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to look at your code to come up with a solution. Don't use the xmm register. Those are SIMD instructions, and since the rest of your code is using the x87 FPU, I recommend continue using x87 FPU instructions.

It appears your code properly sums all the numbers in the array and leaves that sum in register *st(0)*. You also have the number of items to divide by in *ECX* . So you need to divide *st(0)* by the integer value in *ECX*.

To accomplish this you must temporarily store the value of *ECX* in a temporary memory variable. This is because the [FIDIV instruction](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_91.html) doesn't take register operands. What `FIDIV` will do is divide *st(0)* (top of FPU stack) and divide it by a 32-bit integer specified by a 32-bit memory location.

You would need to first add a `.data` section to your function to hold the integer value (numitems):

```
.data
numitems DWORD 0  
.code
```

Instead of what you were trying here:

```
line1   cvtsi2sd eax, xmm0  ;load array size as float to compute average
line2   fdivp               ;divide st(0) by st(1) and pop register stack
```

Do this:

```
mov numitems, ecx           ;Move ecx(# of items in array) to numitems variable
FIDIV numitems              ;divide st(0) by value in numitems variable
                            ;After division st(0) should contain the average
```

The  code would look like this:

```
.686
.model flat

.code 
_average PROC
        .data
        numitems DWORD 0  
        .code

        push ebp                ; save the caller frame pointer
        mov ebp, esp

        mov ebx, [ebp+8]    ; address of first element in array
        mov ecx, [ebp+12]   ; store size of array in ecx
        xor edx, edx        ; counter for loop
        fldz            ; set top of FPU stack to zero

loopAdd:
        fld dword ptr[ebx+edx*4]   ; load next array onto register stack at st(1)
        faddp              ; add st(0) to st(1) and pop register stack
        inc edx            ; increment counter
        cmp ecx, edx           ; compare size of array in ecx with counter in edx
        jg loopAdd         ; if ecx > edx jump to loopAdd and continue

        mov numitems, ecx  ;Move ecx(# of items in array) to numitems variable
        FIDIV numitems     ;divide st(0) by value in numitems variable
                           ;After division st(0) should contain the average

        pop ebp            ; restore caller frame pointer
        ret                ; content of st(0) is returned 

_average ENDP

END
```

This function isn't re-entrant because it effectively uses a static variable `numitems` to temporarily store *ECX* . One can get rid of this temporary static variable by placing the value on the stack temporarily and doing `FIDIV`. The code for that eliminates the `.data` section and uses the 4 bytes just below the current stack pointer long enough to do the `FIDIV` and then the integer value is simply discarded.

```
.686
.model flat

.code 
_average PROC
        push ebp                ; save the caller frame pointer
        mov ebp, esp

        mov ebx, [ebp+8]    ; address of first element in array
        mov ecx, [ebp+12]   ; store size of array in ecx
        xor edx, edx        ; counter for loop
        fldz            ; set top of FPU stack to zero

loopAdd:
        fld dword ptr[ebx+edx*4]   ; load next array onto register stack at st(1)
        faddp              ; add st(0) to st(1) and pop register stack
        inc edx            ; increment counter
        cmp ecx, edx           ; compare size of array in ecx with counter in edx
        jg loopAdd         ; if ecx > edx jump to loopAdd and continue

        mov [esp-4], ecx  ;Move ecx(# of items in array) to temp location on stack
        fidiv dword ptr [esp-4] 
                           ;divide st(0) by value in temporary stack location
                           ;After division st(0) should contain the average

        pop ebp            ; restore caller frame pointer
        ret                ; content of st(0) is returned 
_average ENDP
END
```

As an alternative, since *ECX* was passed in on the stack already at memory location *EBP+12*, the last example can be modified by removing all these lines

```
    mov [esp-4], ecx  ;Move ecx(# of items in array) to temp location on stack
    fidiv dword ptr [esp-4] 
                       ;divide st(0) by value in temporary stack location
                       ;After division st(0) should contain the average
```

And replacing it with this line:

```
    fidiv dword ptr [ebp+12] 
                       ;divide st(0) by SIZE (2nd argument passed on stack)
                       ;After division st(0) should contain the average
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for your time! I greatly appreciate it because you got me on the right track to understand the FPU and I found myself giggling with excitement. Hope you have a great night!

Comment: @drnips Glad it helped. If the answer did in fact help answer your question you can  `accept the answer` so that Stackoverflow can flag it as solved. If you are new to SO, and want to know about how and why to accept answers, please see this information: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/271768

Comment: @drnips: Thanks for accepting this answer and thanks for accepting the answer of the other person who helped you a little while back. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
cvtsi2sd xmm0, ecx
fdiv xmm0
```

It does look too simple...

```
CVTSI2SD xmm, r/m32 Convert one signed doubleword integer from r/m32 to one double-precision floating-point value in xmm.

FDIV m32fp  Divide ST(0) by m32fp and store result in ST(0).
```

Comment: Using xmm at all doesn't work. I get an error "error A2085: instruction or register". I can't find any helpful fix for it. =/